# liquid layout with footer and content splited in two

Tags: html, css

I want to build a liquid layout with a footer that keeps on the end of page and a contend space splited into two divs. I already saw on stackoverflow both examples separated of this two behaviors. how can I implement this?

Note that my left and right colunmns has no content. This is because I'll put a background image and other divs inside it.

I already have one example: http://jsfiddle.net/kpDDM/14/

There is something wrong on my example because when my content area has much content, the content area is not expanding in vertical.

Comment: Minor typo in `.footer` CSS. Change `botton:0` to `bottom:0`

Comment: Do you know why there is a scroll bar when I resize my windows in vertical? http://jsfiddle.net/kpDDM/12/embedded/result/

Comment: There is something wrong on my example because when my content area has much content, the content area is not expanding in vertical.

Comment: That's because you've set `overflow:hidden` to the content `div`s

Comment: There are other problems when I remove the overflow:hidden. The div that has no content disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, http://jsfiddle.net/kpDDM/16/

Added `position:fixed;` to `.footer`, and removed `overflow:hidden` from `.all`.

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/kpDDM/18/

Comment: do you accept work as freelancer professional? I'm asking you here because I looked for a way to send private message I haven't found this way.

Comment: fixing position doesn't work for me because I want a scroll bar on page and the footer should become not visible and stay in the end of page when there are much content.

Comment: Hehe, nope. I'm here only to answer a few questions and help others. If you run into more trouble, feel free to ask on SO. Do you want the footer to always be visible at the bottom of the page when you have a lot of content, or do you want it to be visible when you scroll right to the bottom?

Comment: And I want my left div take all available space without put any content there, because I will put a background image inside the div.

Comment: Thank you very much for attencion. One more about this. I want to build a liquid layout. Is there a way to use 100% height for content instead of 700px?